# How to add mysql driver for Qt 5.11.2 in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu

I'm want to run a Qt project which uses mysql database. Please provide a step by step instruction, preferably with some explanation, how to add mysql driver to Qt 5.11.2. I'm beginner level in linux and Qt. I tried different guides from internet but none of them worked for me.

Comment: How did you install QT?

Answer (score -1):

Write this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5sql5-mysql
```

Comment: OK, I had it already installed. Still my sql support doesn't work in Qt. When running Qt project I get: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded